# Can I have a header work as a button but not use the role of a button

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a header that I want to work as a button. My problem is that if I assign the header a button role, it messes with accebility and a screen reader; The button role overrides the header so the blind user can not navigate to the header as they would with other headers.

I want the user to be able to navigate to the header and push it like a button (using the space bar). I have been trying to nest a button into the header with a changed tab index but it does not work.

```
<h2 class="navigation_title" tabindex="0">
     <span role="button" class="navigation_title_text" tabindex="-1">
</span></h2>
```

**Any ideas of how I can have a header work as a button but not use the role of a button?**

Comment: Have you looked into javascripts `onclick` function? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: How did you implement this? How do you make the heading act as a button, and what does it do?

Answer (score 4):

I interpret the question so that you have assigned some scripted event to an heading element and you would therefore want to assign the `button` role to it, in addition to the default `heading` role. And this is meant to improve accessibility so that the element would be treated both as a heading, e.g. in “headings reading mode”, and as a button, e.g. so that assistive software could inform the user about a button that can be activated.

According to the WAI ARIA spec, the [`role` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#host_general_role) allows a space-separated list of role identifiers as its value, but only the first one is used. So setting `role="heading button"`, while formally allowed (HTML5 validators have a [bug](https://bugzilla.validator.nu/show_bug.cgi?id=1011) that reports it as an error), is taken as identical with `role="heading"`. This means that you can only one role for an element instance.

(Moreover, W3C HTML5 Rec defines [`h2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) so that the only allowed roles are `heading`, `tab`, and `presentation`.)

You can wrap a `span` inside an `h2` element as in the question, or an `h2` inside a `div`, and declare the role of the `span` or `div` element to `button`. However, this makes one the elements a heading and another element a button, in WAI terms. The situation that you cannot assign a single element two roles reflects implementations: they cannot be expected to handle the same element in two ways.

From a more general accessibility point of view, considering also cognitive problems, this is reasonable: Even if you could make an element act both as a heading and as a button (as you technically can, up to a point, but not in WAI sense), users would have a cognitive challenge. When they encounter something that walks like a heading, talks like a heading, they won’t expect it to to a push button as well.

Given the abstractness of the description, it is impossible to suggest other approaches. But a solution *might* consist of simply having a button, with short text, after each heading (possibly on the same line).

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with this? Simplify everyone's lives by using a real `<button>`:

```
<h2 class="navigation_title">
    <button class="navigation_title_text">
        Foo
    </button>
</h2>

<script>
    $('.navigation_title_text').click(function () {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<h2 class="navigation_title" tabindex="0">
     <span onclick="myFunction()" class="navigation_title_text" tabindex="-1">
</span></h2>
```

By using onclick attribute you make this element clickable
My function could be anything you like

Comment: This won't work from a keyboard (you'd have to hook up key event handlers manually for that). And the `role` attribute is required for screen readers. The sensible thing to do is to just use a *real* `<button>` element.